# RAM upgrade - memory detected but not loading OS

Tags: laptop, memory, upgrade

I'm trying to upgrade memory of an HP Probook 6550b laptop. I happen to have a Dell inspiron with 2 branches:

`4GB PC3L 12800S Part number: HMT451S6BFR8A (manu: hynix)`

The RAM on my probook should according to what I understand in [this](http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c03471180) work (search DDR3 for references or go to p.4 of chapter one).

The computer will boot. System info at startup will show 8192 mb of ram, which is what I inserted (2 slots). However, when I try to actually boot it shuts down. Similarly if I try to run memory tests.

Note that I am trying to use a PC3L in a PC3 slot - but according to a similar question on this exchange, this should be fine.

Is there something I may have to do to make this work, or is the ram I'm trying to put in just not compatible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the RAM does not work, then you bought the wrong one.
I hope you can still be reimbursed for it.

The funny thing is that when I go on the
[Skhynix RAM selection page](https://www.skhynix.com/products.do?lang=eng&ct1=36&ct2=38&rc=com),
and I enter 4GB and 1.35V, I already get other RAM sticks than the one you bought.
In fact, yours is not at all in the list.

Fitting RAM to a computer is an extremely complex operation.
To appreciate how complex this is, see
[this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1252970/8672)
of mine.

If you wish to get RAM that is guaranteed to work, go to the
[Crucial website](http://www.crucial.com/), and download and use the
Crucial System Scanner.
It will scan your hardware and give you a list or RAM sticks that will fit it.
The prices of Crucial are competitive and the RAM is guaranteed.

Comment: I'm trying to salvage RAM I already have from another computer - would be nice if it worked but not a huge deal if not. It's a somewhat older laptop, therefore probably not the latest ram brnaches (but then the computer I'm trying to fit it on isn't new either).

I guess I'll check with crucial & order some then... Thanks.