# How can I determine if I can place my HDD and RAM in another laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, memory

I bought an HP Envy 15j laptop a long time ago. While all the electronic components are still working, part of the chassis was broken, and the replacement parts are expensive and unavailable in my country.

How can I determine if the HDD and RAM will fit in another laptop (I plan on buying an inexpensive second-hand laptop)?

(And don't worry, I know not to buy any kind of portable laptop, which couldn't contain the parts even if I managed to connect them)

Comment: HDDs or SSDs usually work. RAM may work if the same type and does not exceed the maximum capacity per slot of the target system.

Comment: @MichaelBay but what do I need to check to make sure? I'm guessing make sure it uses the same connections, but is there anything else I need to worry about?

Comment: Unlike data storage units, RAM has several different and incompatible types and that should be your starting point, assuring the target system supports the same memory type. Then, the only other limitation is the maximum RAM, both total and per slot, supported by the target system. Honestly, if you're asking this kind of questions you'd be better asking a professional to do it.

Comment: For disk compare the interface specs. However, RAM compatibility is an extremely complicated question - see [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1252970/8672). You may compare the metrics of your RAM and the motherboard (or at least those that you have available). Even if they match, the final test may be to try and see.

Comment: @harrymc Thank you! at least now I know what to look at (interface specs & the things listen in the answer you linked). I suppose if need be I can buy new RAM that I know to be compatible.
If you post this as an answer, I'll accept & upvote it :)

MichaelBay: then how would I learn? Also, I tried professionals. They aren't open to the idea of helping me find an alternate chassis/compatible second-hand computer.

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the disk you only need to compare the interface specs : IDE, EIDE, SCSI, SAS, SATA 1/2/3 etc.

RAM compatibility is a much more complicated question.
[This answer](https://superuser.com/a/1252970/8672)
lists most of the metrics involved, probably more than you have available.

You may compare the metrics of your RAM and the motherboard.
Motherboards usually accept a range for most of the metrics,
as specified in the manual, so an exact match is not always required.

Even if the RAM metrics match, the final test may be just to try and see.