# Matching RAM to laptop - what are the essentials?

Tags: laptop, memory, motherboard, upgrade

According to [enter link description here](https://superuser.com/questions/1250578/what-exactly-is-the-cause-of-ram-incompatibility/1252970#1252970), getting the right RAM for your laptop is very difficult.

I tried following this, but found I couldn't get some of the necessary information. So I looked around, and found claims that this is actually much simpler.

For example, [article on laptop RAM](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/upgrading-a-laptops-ram-step-by-step-si-x2/), all you actually need to know if form factor, type of RAM (DDR/DDR2/DDR3/DDR4), and clock speed. I also found an answer here on superuser which makes the same claim.

I understand that some mismatches can cause, for example, an inability to use ALL of the RAM (obviously if the motherboard only supports 4GB per card, it won't be able to use all the 8GB on the RAM I have).

But what exactly is essential? Assuming my RAM is properly made, do I really need any more parameters than the form factor (SODIMM for laptops), frequency and RAM type?

(I also read something about non-ECC unbuffered being the most common, so that's one more simple parameter)

Edit: To clarify, I'm familiar with the Crucial tool.
What I'd like to know is what exactly is the basis for the claim that the RAMs match the laptop. Is it just form factor, speed, RAM type and the max number of GB each slot in the motherboard can handle, or does one have to consider more factors, assuming the RAM chip is up to standard?

Comment: Go to [Crucial US | DRAM, Solid State Drive (SSD) & Memory Upgrades](http://www.crucial.com/) - it will tell you exactly what kind of memory to get.

Comment: @DavidPostill I've come across this multiple times, but now that I have suggestions, the question is-  are the details in the page of the suggested memories ALL that I need to know? e.x. I have: Specs: DDR3 PC3-12800 • CL=11 • Unbuffered • NON-ECC • DDR3-1600 • 1.35V • 1024Meg x 64. It also says SODIMM under form factor. If I have RAM with the same characteristics as those, is that enough to know it will work?

Comment: I believe so ...

Comment: Kingston and Crucial guarantee compatibility, that is all you need to know.

Comment: @Moab but I don't want to buy from them. I have RAM. I'm not made of money, I don't want to buy a new one... I want to make sure mine is compatible, and it's not one of theirs.

Comment: As long as it is the same specs, put it in the laptop and test it... It will either work or not work.

Comment: @acejavelin I haven't bought the laptop yet... this is why I'm asking. I'd like to know what I need to look out for when buying a refurbished one.

Comment: You also need to know if it's registered,  the maximum amount of memory the system can take and the acceptable pairing(not normally an issue on laptops)

Comment: @davidgo right! the buffered-unbuffered thing. And what's "acceptable pairing"? just to make sure. Now I have parameters which I always see for the memory modules and I can get all the data I need to ensure compatibility.

Comment: Sometimes you have to configure ram in pairs, or in certain slots. This is generally only an issue on desktops and server which have more slots, but check on the crucial site - it has a diagram with pairings and slots for each system.

Comment: It's also very unlikely, but a manufacturer can lock the BIOS to only support certain makes)models if RAM.

Comment: @davidgo Thank you! I'll make sure whatever I buy isn't locked/supports what I have.