# PC goes into endless reboot loop after filling all RAM slots

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, bios

My PC goes into endless reboot loop after filling all RAM slots. There's no POST screen nor audible error code. After powering on, it takes ~15s before it shuts down and powers on again.

Until recently, I had 2x Corsair CMK32GX4M2A2400C14R (v5.30) configuration and system worked well. Now with the second pair of CMK32GX4M2A2400C14R (v8.31) and therefore all slots filled, system goes into this endless reboot cycle.

If I read the [manual](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/AB350%20Pro4/#Memory) right, presented configuration should be fine. How can I troubleshoot the problem? Or maybe I am just doomed to a single RAM pair?

Important remarks:

- All memory slots are fine
- Both memory pairs are OK (tested)
- Clearing CMOS with jumper did not help

Relevant hardware:

- Mobo: Asrock AB350 Pro4 v1.01 (BIOS 5.40)
- CPU: Ryzen 1700X

EDIT: Below you will find the [specs](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/AB350%20Pro4/#Specification) from AsRock for Summit Ridge family (where Ryzen 1700X belongs).

[image]

Comment: What happens if you a) install only the new pair but not the old one, or b) install only 3 memory modules – both originals plus just one or the other from the new pair?

Comment: @grawity New modules work, regardless of the slot. Inserting third causes same issue as all 4 inserted.

Comment: In the [full manual](http://asrock.pc.cdn.bitgravity.com/Manual/AB350%20Pro4.pdf) page 22, section on memory, it says to look for **SR:** *Single rank DIMM, 1Rx4 or 1Rx8 on DIMM module label* or **DR:** *Dual rank DIMM, 2Rx4 or 2Rx8 on DIMM module label* - Which kind are yours? Wasn't able to find on the internet.

Comment: @Mołot I thought the same, but then the specs on the web site, which should be in theory more up to date, show that DR should work (see my edit). However, if somehow I don't read it right, then this is likely cause of problems.

Comment: So it should work for both DR and SR, and thus it does not really matter which kind your RAM is. "Good" for you but that means I don't have any ideas right now.

Comment: @Mołot I've heard a statement that it's much more of a lottery if two separate kit of the same kind are going to work together. Do you know if it's true? According to that, I should have bought a single 4x16 GB kit. Thing is, all the kits that AsRock says are compatible, are no longer being sold (not to mention extra cost).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What exactly is the cause of RAM incompatibility?](https://superuser.com/questions/1250578/what-exactly-is-the-cause-of-ram-incompatibility)

Answer (score 0):

According to the tech support of AsRock the most likely cause, with no remedy, is the version difference between the modules that likely results in different chip and / or layout. Full answer:

> different revision/versions of memory modules can give problems. We
>   suggest to use 4 identical modules. Your modules have ver 5.30 and
>   8.31 Seems like the different versions have different chips and/or different layout. So they might not work together at all. Better check
>   with Corssair.   Also we do not have same memory modules tested and
>   shown in our memory QVL – we had only tested the CL16 modules. Yours
>   are CL14 https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/AB350%20Pro4/index.asp#MemoryPR