# Not Able To Use Brand New RAM Modules

Tags: windows-10, memory

This is my first question in this forum, please help me to solve my problem. Recently, I purchased another RAM module to upgrade my Windows 10 setup. But even after the upgrade, it still shows 15.9GB (12 GB usable). I don't know why it looks like that. Has anyone encountered such errors before? Please help me. Any kind feedback would be highly appreciated.

Current system setup:

- OS: Windows 10 Pro 64 bit
- RAM: 8Gigs Corsair Vengeance DDR4 3600 Mhz
- Mobo: MSI B450
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600

Comment: Did you check on crucial.com if they are compatible?

Comment: There are different motherboards that can be described as an MSI B450

Comment: There are different RAM sticks that can be described as "8Gigs Corsair Vengeance"

Comment: RAM stick is of DDR4 3600 Mhz

Comment: What is the original ram stick that was already in there?

Comment: What precisely is your issue? Your RAM shows 15.9GB… that's close enough for jazz on 2 8GB modules [you didn't, btw, tell us what you had before vs what you have now, you left us to guess that much]. Is it that the graphics structure is using shared memory & you weren't aware, or didn't know how/why that happens? What were the figures before you added the RAM?

Comment: Before it was showing 7.9GB when I had only one RAM stick, but after upgrading to 16 GB it is showing 12GB, not 16GB.

Comment: Ignore the answers suggesting your hardware does not support 16 GB.  If that was the case it wouldn't detect 16 GB, if it wasn't supported, it likely wouldn't even boot.  However, "15.9GB (12 GB usable)", suggests some of your memory is being hardware reserved. Can you provide a screenshot of RAMMap by chance?  Be sure you edit your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: Check your manual for correct ram placement (especially if your board has more then 2 RAM slots). If they are slotted correct, try swapping them around.

Answer (score 0):

I compare your RAM with the one that is offered by
[crucial.com](https://www.crucial.com/)
for the
[B450 GAMING PLUS](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/msi-(micro-star)/b450-gaming-plus),
which is one motherboard variant among the several that exist.

Your RAM exceeds the maximum that Crucial advises on several
attributes:

- Yours is DDR4 3600, while Crucial advises at most DDR4-3200
- Yours is PC4-28800, while Crucial advises at most PC4-25600

I suggest downloading and running the Crucial Advisor by clicking
the button of "Start your scan" on the Crucial website,
then pay attention to what it advises.
I find the results of the Crucial Advisor to be very correct
and are guaranteed by Crucial (and the prices are competitive).

The problem of RAM compatibility is complex.
See the post
[What exactly is the cause of RAM incompatibility?](https://superuser.com/questions/1250578/what-exactly-is-the-cause-of-ram-incompatibility)

Answer (score 0):

Some guy on the internet claims that swapping the RAM to a different slot changed the amount available from 12gb to 16gb https://linustechtips.com/topic/745635-16gb-ram-12gb-usable-why/

Comment: Yeah, I tried swapping the RAM modules but was not affecting the total usable RAM. Then [this](https://bottobotto.com/ram-not-showing-up/) random article helped me to solve the issue. Actually, the Windows System Configuration was limiting the maximum memory that can be used on my system. I just unchecked the box in Advance Boot Option, and restarted my system, then it changed my total usable RAM storage. Thanks everyone for your valuable support.

Comment: @GiovaniGibson Ah, didn't know that. Just in case someone else happens to have the same problem in the future and comes across this page I have archived that page: https://web.archive.org/web/20211116134841/https://bottobotto.com/ram-not-showing-up/