# RAM wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity doesent match motherboard manufacturer

Tags: memory, motherboard, memory-management, ramdisk

The issue is that I have a Bangho brand notebook (Argentina) that has the following mother: W130EW, manufacturer clevo (source: https://www.clevo.com.tw/clevo_down.asp?lang=en)

Its specification says that it supports 8gb but when I use the command `wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity, MemoryDevices` it tells me that it supports 16gb.

So what is my actual memory capacity?

Comment: The `wmic` command assumes that you have all the memory channels available along with multiple DIMMs on each channel. It is the *processor* maximum. Most commercial processors have 2 channels with 2 DIMMS per channel. Your motherboard manufacturer may not have wired up multiple channels or DIMM slots and if you can only fit 2 DIMMs (when the processor supports 4) then you will have half the memory capability.

Comment: Before all thank you for taking the time to answer Mokubai, so how could I check this: "Your Motherboard Manufacturer May Not Have Wired Up Multiple Channels or Dimm Slots and If You Can Only Fit 2 Dimms (When The Processor Supports 4) Will Have Half The Memory Capability "? From already thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think both are right.

The
[manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1156968/Clevo-W150hrm.html?page=14#)
says this :

[image]

I would take this that you have two RAM slots,
where each is expendable to 8GB.

Now, 2x8GB=16GB, and this ends this mystery.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering Harrymc but, if both are well, could you buy 2 8GB memories and should you accept them?

Comment: [RAM compatibility](https://superuser.com/questions/1250578/what-exactly-is-the-cause-of-ram-incompatibility) is a big question, depending on both the motherboard and CPU. That's why I recommend using the [Crucial System Scanner](https://www.crucial.com/) that analyzes all the factors. I suggest also to never buy RAM from a vendor without a good return policy.

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please consider marking it as accepted (click the ✔ sign).