# Memory doesn't seem to be compatible with my ASUS motherboard, how can I solve the issue?

Tags: memory, motherboard, asus

I just bought adata memory and an ASUS Z690 ROG Maximus Apex board. The memory is ADATA XPG Lancer 6000mhz 2x16gb sticks.

I can't get the board to boot to bios, I get Q code 12 for about a minute (which means that the board is trying to sync w/ the memory), then I get a Q code 55, which as far as I can tell, means it failed. Adata says the memory is supposed to be comparable, is there anything I can do to get it working? Should I buy another memory kit? If I can't get to bios then is there any troubleshooting steps I can do other than trying the different dimms and clearing CMOS?

Comment: When you buy RAM, use the manufacturer's guide, e.g., Kingston's, https://www.redcorp.com/en/QuickFinder/Memory , or Crucial's: https://www.crucial.com/store/advisor . If that advice is wrong, then you have a basis to request return and refund.

Comment: Yeah I did do that. They said it would work but i am pretty sure it's not able to sync.

Comment: Per [this resource from asus](https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-maximus/rog-maximus-z690-apex-model/helpdesk_qvl_memory/) that ram should be compatible.

Comment: Try updating your Bios, you should be able to do it with Bios Flashback even if it's not posting, i just had a similar issue with a PC I built.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Facts :

- The RAM upgrades for your computer by
  [Crucial](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/asus/rog-maximus-z690-apex)
  are all 1.1V.
- The
  [Lancer RGB DDR5 DRAM Module](https://www.adata.com/en/xpg/DRAM-modules-LANCER-RGB-DDR5?tab=specification)
  is specified for Operating Voltage as 1.25V-1.4V.

The two just don't match. You bought the wrong RAM, so better return it
and ask for reimbursement.

Choosing the right RAM is a complicated process. You can see some of the
complexity in the post
[What exactly is the cause of RAM incompatibility?](https://superuser.com/questions/1250578/what-exactly-is-the-cause-of-ram-incompatibility)

That's why you need to carefully use documentation and aids by RAM
manufacturers such as Crucial for being sure of getting the
right RAM.
Using Crucial or any other RAM manufacturer is safe, because
Crucial guarantees compatibility.

Comment: I might not be rated very high here, but I do contribute to stack overflow quite often. I can say with confidence that this is an outstanding answer, and I am greatful for it. Looking at it it might sound like common since, but I wrote software, and just started learning about the hardware end of things. Ty very much.

Comment: Not sure the voltage is an issue, there are plenty of memory modules listed by ASUS that need the same voltages: https://rog.asus.com/uk/motherboards/rog-maximus/rog-maximus-z690-apex-model/helpdesk_qvl_memory/, even various ADATA 6000 MHz modules

Comment: Yeah, I see compatible modules from 1.1v to 1.4v, which is pretty normal for a modern mobo. ASUS and ADATA both specify that these modules should be compatible with your mobo. Try reseating, using only one module at a time (in each slot). Make sure nothing's at a weird angle or had to be forced into place.

Comment: This answer is just wrong. The JEDEC voltage is 1.1V but the overclocked profiles (XMP) will contain/configure higher voltages that you'll need to reach the 6000 MHz clock speeds. This is entirely normal for any overclocked RAM (otherwise you'd only have the 4800 MHz or 5200 MHz JEDEC clocks available). Most any modern motherboard supporting XMP/higher-clock profiles will support those higher voltages.

Answer (score 4):

DDR5 memory compatibility is still very hit-or-miss at this point.

Try to put in a single stick and hope that it will boot.
Then try to do a BIOS update (which will hopefully increase compatibility).

If your board has a "USB BIOS flashback" option, you might be able to flash the BIOS directly from a USB flash drive without needing working memory.

You can also try to increase the DRAM voltage a little bit, if you're brave enough. This will cause extra heating in the DRAM chips and waste a bit of energy, but shouldn't otherwise have any negative side effects.

Worst case, you'd have to borrow (or buy) a stick of compatible memory to get into the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Check the motherboard's [memory QVL](https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-maximus/rog-maximus-z690-apex-model/helpdesk_qvl_memory/)

If your RAM is not on the list then you bought the wrong RAM.

DDR5 support is notoriously finicky so stick to the QVL.