# 4 sticks of ram wont boot?

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard

I tried using 4 sticks of RAM, but my system won't boot. All 4 sticks are same type and model (purchased both sets at same time from same vendor) and I tried many different configurations to no avail. Using slots A1 and B1 with 1 set will boot and run fine though? And I have tested every stick separately and the system booted fine with no issues so that isn't the problem either. Is the motherboard/CPU only able to handle so much RAM? It says it can support 128GB but I'm only putting in 64GB (16GB x 4). Any ideas? I will post build below:

- ASRock B550 Pro4, BIOS Ver 3.3
- Ryzen 5 3600
- NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060
- 1TB HDD, 250GB SSD (1TB SSD available but not installed)
- Corsair Vengeance RGB Pro SL 32GB (2x16GB) two sets
- Windows 11 Home

Everything is compatible according to Part Checker but I am a novice at building so who knows? Please help.

Comment: It's a LOT more complicated that what you think: https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/B550%20Pro4/index.asp#Specification You must be sure about your CPU then find out what types of DDR4 can be used and the specific configurations according to the tables.

Comment: wild guess, is your PSU able to supply all the electricity to power your CPU, the GPU and the ram, etc?

Comment: Yeah, I checked configurations to make sure on how to place them. I guess the board just cant support that much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The
[B550 Pro4](https://www.asrock.com/mb/AMD/B550%20Pro4/index.asp#Specification)
has this table for your CPU (which is from the Matisse family):

[image]

However, your RAM is the
"VENGEANCE RGB PRO SL 32 GO (2 x 16 GO) DDR4 DRAM **3 600 MHz** C18".

As you can see from the above table, the number of supported RAM sticks
reduces as the frequency goes up, and yours is already above all of
the values in the table. You may already be thankful that the motherboard
accepts two of the sticks, because the table shows that sometimes
it may accept only one.

It's usually safer to pick your RAM from a RAM-picker, such as in
[Crucial](https://www.crucial.com/compatible-upgrade-for/asrock/b550-pro4#memory),
or even better the
[Crucial System Scanner](https://www.crucial.com/store/systemscanner)
that will suggest all compatible upgrades.
Crucial RAM is reasonably priced and the scanner results are
guaranteed.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I didn't know about frequency and stuff until recently and I still don't fully understand it lol. I went with these RAM only because of availability and the RGB. Again, I'm still a novice.

Comment: The Crucial System Scanner might be the best solution.

Comment: I think because the BIOS has the frequency set at 3200 it allows two sticks to work. Would reducing it further down to 2933 make a difference?

Comment: I can't state what will be the result. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1252970/8672) to appreciate the enormous complexity of RAM compatibility. There are just too many variables. The Crucial System Scanner takes care of all the variables when it examines your hardware, so you could try running it to just see which kinds of RAM upgrades it suggests (frequency and other attributes).